# Trouble with backpropogation in a vectorized implementation of a simple neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have been going through [UFLDL](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL_Tutorial) tutorials.In the vectorized implementation of a simple neural net, the tutorials suggest that one way to do this would be to go through the entire training set instead of iterative approach. In the back propogation part, this would mean replacing:

```
 gradW1 = zeros(size(W1));
 gradW2 = zeros(size(W2)); 

for i=1:m,
  delta3 = -(y(:,i) - h(:,i)) .* fprime(z3(:,i)); 
  delta2 = W2'*delta3(:,i) .* fprime(z2(:,i));

  gradW2 = gradW2 + delta3*a2(:,i)';
  gradW1 = gradW1 + delta2*a1(:,i)'; 
end;
```

with

```
delta3 = -(y - h) .* fprime(z3)
delta2 = W2'*delta3().*fprime(z2)

gradW2 = delta3*a2'
gradW1 = delta2*a1' 
//apply weight correction now that all gradients
//are computed
```

Please visit [this page](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/UFLDL_Tutorial) for information about the notation and the algorithm.

However this implementation yielded abnormally large values inside gradW1 and gradW2. This seems to be a result of me not updating the weights as I process each training input(tested this on another earlier working implementation). Am I right about this? From reading the tutorials it seems that there is a way to make this work, but I can't come up with something that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backpropogation has two ways of implementation: batch and online training algorithm. Initially you described online training algorithm. Then you found and tried to implement batch training algorithm which sometime has side effect which you described. In your case it can be good idea to split learning samples into smaller chunks and learn on them.